# How to find a TFS alert not set up by you

Tags: tfs

Someone has 'helpfully' set up a TFS 2008 Alert for a build on my behalf.  I want to turn it off but no one will own up and I can't find it.  Reading the docs suggests only the creator can see it.  Is there anyway to find it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a codeplex tool that I've used in the past to subscribe and unsubscribe outside of the UI:

http://tfseventsubscription.codeplex.com/

You could also do it through the commandline using the `BisSubscribe.exe` tool that is installed on the TFS server.